# How can I get a KxK matrix in matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix, equation-solving

In my assignment my lecturer wants me to write an equation solver in matlab but I need to get an input . Input will be the K in KxK matrix and I need to get K time(s) multiple of unknown. Let me know if there is an spesific operator for this.I couldn't find any tutorial video btw. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The functions [`zeros`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/zeros.html) and [`ones`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ones.html) do that:

```matlab
k = 3
A = zeros(k)
B = ones(k)
```

In this example, A should be a `3x3` array filled with zeros, and `B` should also be 3x3, filled with ones. If you need to specify types or non-square matrices, check the documentation I linked in the beginning of the post.